# URL rewrite not working, a2enmod active, using Override All, .htaccess correct

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

**The issue**

I have installed a Wordpress. I have turned on Pretty Permalinks (Post name). Any page other than the homepage is a `404 Not Found`. This seems to indicate a rewrite issue.

**My set up**

Ubunutu 14.04
Using localhost as my URL
My apache config is `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`
My wordpress is located at `/var/www/wordpress/`
My relevant htaccess is located at `/var/www/wordpress/.htaccess`

**What I've tried**

When I run `a2enmod rewrite` I get

```
Module rewrite already enabled
```

My `.htaccess`

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

My `000-default.conf` file apache config

```
<Directory /var/www/wordpress/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

I've tried all the answers at the canonical question for this.

[How to enable mod_rewrite for Apache 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2)

**My question**

Why is my rewrite not working?

Comment: Your Apache version is 2.2 too?

Comment: Check `apache2ctl -t -D DUMP_MODULES` and `apache2ctl -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS` , see also your log files. Add relevant outputs to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps to check proper vhost configuration:
Check if there is a "*vhostname*.conf" file in your "sites-available" directory. Then check if there is a valid symlink to that file in "sites-enabled" directory. You can create a missing site symlink by `a2ensite vhostname`. Open this file in an editor. It should contain something like

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@sitename.net
    ServerName  sitename.net
    ServerAlias www.site-name.net

    DocumentRoot /var/www/site-folder/htdocs

    <Directory /var/www/site-folder/htdocs/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            DirectoryIndex index.php7 index.php5 index.php index.html
            AllowOverride All

# apache 2.2 and below only (following 3 lines)
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
            Deny from none

# apache 2.4 only
            Require all granted  
    </Directory>
```

Ensure that the `DocumentRoot` folder has a matching `<Directory /path/to/docroot>` block. Place into this block `AllowOverride All` or any selective permission you want to allow to be overridden in ".htaccess".

Ensure the rewrite module is enabled.

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

After modifying configurations don't forget to restart/reload apache.

```
sudo apache2ctl graceful
```

Check if the module and the vhost config was loaded.

```
apache2ctl -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS
apache2ctl -t -D DUMP_MODULES
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that I needed to edit the apache config at `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` and change the `/var/www/` Directory to `AllowOverride All`

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

I would have thought that my `000-default.conf` would have overrode this but that was not the case and this fixed the issue.

Comment: My apache2.conf is set to `None` on `/` and `/var/www` and rewrite is working fine.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone Agreed it is unexpected, however it fixed the issue for me and I didn't seen this answer to this issue on StackOverflow so this may be helpful to others.

Comment: This answer was already posted on the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2) you've linked (37 upvotes). It seems to solve config problems, however, it's a strange behavior (not working without) and I wouldn't like to have such settings on productive systems.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone That answer instructs to edit `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-deafult` which I already have tried unsuccessfully. I agree it's not ideal, and no it will not be used on production. If you can find a more direct solution, I will accept.

Comment: Can you post your complete 000-default.conf? And have you enabled this site config? Is there a symlink in sites-enabled?

Comment: I took a look at the rest of `000-default.conf` and saw `DocumentRoot /var/www/html`. This looks wrong. If you think this is causing the issue, post it as an answer and I'll accept.